# Pentaho CDE Table component format cell values

Tags: pentaho-cde

I want to format the cells of all columns based on some range. So, I want to color the text red or green. I have set the data type of all the columns to "formattedText". And in the "Pre-Execution", I have the following Add-In.

```
function f(){  
    this.setAddInOptions("colType","formattedText",function(cell_data){
        //alert(ExceedingLow);

        var percentage = '';            
        if(cell_data.colIdx == 7) {
            percentage = cell_data.value;
            return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:red'>"+v+"</span>"; } };
        }
        /*if(cell_data.colIdx == 7)
        {
            if(cell_data.value === '' || cell_data.value === null)
            {
                this.value = '00000';
            }
        }*/
        /*if(cell_data.colIdx == 7) {
            return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:red'>"+v+"</span>"; } };
        }*/

      });   
 }//main function ending
```

When I add this code in Pre-Execution property, I get an error which says, "Unexpected Identifier" for **Extra Options** property.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Code portion in bold below dis the trick.

Here's the working code:

```
 function f(){  
    this.setAddInOptions("colType","formattedText",function(cell_data){
        //alert(ExceedingLow);

        var val = cell_data.value;

            if (val.indexOf("/") != -1) 
            {
                    **return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return st.value; }};**
            }
            else if (val.indexOf("/") == -1) 
            {
                 if((val < ExceedingLow || val > ExceedingHigh)) 
                 {

                    return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:red'>"+v+"</span>"; }};
                }
                else 
                {
                    return { textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:green'>"+v+"</span>"; }};
                }
            }
    });   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove commented lines
I faced with a situation that they still are compiled

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.